# Webpack : How to convert variables on build

Tags: javascript, performance, variables, webpack, vue.js

About using **Vue** *(vue-loader)* + **Webpack** and **[Chromatism](https://github.com/toish/chromatism)**

**Example:** (on dev / source)

```
let textColor = chromatism.contrastRatio('#ffea00').cssrgb // => rgb(0,0,0)
```

Does it possible to tell **Webpack to convert** to `rgb(0,0,0)` on **build version**?

So on **build version** should be converted something like: (for **performance**)

```
let textColor = 'rgb(0,0,0)'
```

Comment: I don't believe anyone has written a AOT plugin to handle this. You may have to put in a custom build step yourself, or write a plugin that does this

Comment: This call AOT right ? @JoeyCiechanowicz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As previous answers and comments have already mentioned that there are no readily available AOT compilers to handle this kind of a situation (I mean this is a very specific case and no general purpose tool could be able to handle it), there is nothing stopping you from rolling out your own loader/plugin to handle this task!
You can use a custom [Webpack Loader](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/) and [Node's VM Module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) to execute the code at buildtime, get its output and replace it with the function call in your source file.
A sample implementation of this idea can look like the following snippet:

```
// file: chromatismOptimizer.js

// node's vm module https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html
const vm = require('vm')

const chromatism = require('chromatism')

// a basic and largley incomplete regex to extract lines where chromatism is called
let regex = /^(.*)(chromatism\S*)(.*)$/

// create a Sandbox 
//https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_what_does_it_mean_to_contextify_an_object
// this is roughly equivalent to the global the context the script will execute in
let sandbox = {
  chromatism: chromatism
}

// now create an execution context for the script
let context = new vm.createContext(sandbox)

// export a webpack sync loader function
module.exports = function chromatismOptimizer(source){
  let compiled = source.split('\n').reduce((agg, line) => {
    let parsed = line.replace(regex, (ig, x, source, z) => {
      // parse and execute the script inside the context
      // return value is the result of execution
      // https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_script_runincontext_contextifiedsandbox_options
      let res = (new (vm.Script)(source)).runInContext(context)
      return `${x}'${res}'${z? z : ''}`
    })
    agg.push(parsed)
    return agg;
  }, []).join('\n');

  return compiled;
}
```

Then in your *production.webpack.js* (or somefile like that) taken from [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/903):

```
// Webpack config
resolveLoader: {
  alias: {
    'chromatism-optimizer': path.join(__dirname, './scripts/chromatism-optimizer'),
  },
}
// In module.rules
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  use: ['chromatism-optimizer'],
}
```

**NOTE:** This is just a reference implementation and is largely incomplete. The regex used here is quite basic and may not cover many other use cases, so make sure you update the regex. Also this whole stuff can be implemented using webpack plugins (it's just that I don't have sufficient knowledge of how to create one). For a quick starter [refer to this wiki](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/how-to-write-a-plugin) to learn how to create a custom plugin.

The basic idea is simple.

1. First create  a sandboxed environment,
   `let sandbox = { chromatism:chromatism, ...}`
2. Then create an execution context,
   `let context = new vm.createContext(sandbox)`
3. Then for each valid source, execute the source statement in the context and get the result.
   `let result = (new (vm.Source)(source)).runInContext(context)`
4. Then maybe replace the original source statement with the result.

Comment: Thanks for a great article answer ! I does not tested yet. But seems like this is right way to do. Cheer !

Answer (score 1):

Try using [call-back](https://github.com/Kreozot/callback-loader) loader to process all your JavaScript. Define a callback function for this specific case or even something more general like:

`evalDuringCompile: function(code) { return JSON.stringify(eval(code)); }`

Answer (score 0):

State of Art optimizer cannot handle arbitrary expression. In this case, the most reliable solution is hard code constant in your code like this.

```
let textColor = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'rgb(0,0,0)' :  chromatism.contrastRatio('#ffea00').cssrgb;
```

Some futuristic optimizer does handle situation like this. [prepack](https://github.com/facebook/prepack) will evaluate code at compile time and output computed values. However, it is not generally considered production ready.

Comment: +1 Thanks for **Prepack** ref. But your example does not what I want sorry. I cant set if else shorthand for unknowing variables

Comment: If your code contains non-constant variable. I wonder if prepack or any optimizer will help.